# GWT different interface implementation for client and server

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection

Assume that we've some **interface my.gwt.shared.Facade** in shared package of our GWT project (exists both server and client) and two implementation of it: **class my.gwt.client.ClientFacadeImpl** (exists only client) and **class my.gwt.server.ServerFacadeImpl** (exists only server).

Is there any way to write a piece of code or annotation that substitute **ClientFacadeImpl** in client side and **ServerFacadeImpl** in server side?

Comment: What means "piece of code that substitute"? What substitute?

Comment: Passes ClientFacadeImpl in client runtime and ServerFacadeImpl in server runtime. For example:

    Facade facade = // some code;
    if (GWT.isClient()) {
        facade.getClass(); // ClientFacadeImpl
    } else {
        facade.getClass(); // ServerFacadeImpl
    }

Comment: Do you know that client code translates into JavaScript? So, you must separate your code. Repeated code and common classes (which not depends on client/server side) is placed into shared package.

Comment: Yes, I know that client code compiles to Javascript. But I hope that solution of my problem exists by GWT.create or annotations. This solution will decrease boilerplate code in my project dramatically.

Comment: As I said, boilerplace code should be placed into shared package. If you want to know on which side your code run, you have different code which you must separate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the answers and discussion. I've found simple and elegant solution for my needs.

So, I've **interface my.gwt.shared.Facade** and two classes: **class my.gwt.client.ClientFacadeImpl** and **class my.gwt.server.ServerFacadeImpl**.

```
interface Facade {
    Map<Boolean, Facade> FACADES = new HashMap<Boolean, Facade>();
}
```

Now, we should fill you FACADES interface. This is done like that:

```
public class MyEntry implements EntryPoint {
static {
    Facade.FACADES.put(true, ClientFacadeImpl.INSTANCE); // client side
}
```

And

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Initializer {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        Facade.FACADES.put(false, ServerFacadeImpl.INSTANCE); // server side
        // other things
    }
}
```

Now, when I need to get appropriate Facade, I just write

```
 Facade facade = Facade.FACADES.get(GWT.isClient());
```

Also in this case in map is only corresponding to server or client side implementation.

P. S. Goal of this question was to allow handling of some GwtEvents fired on client direclty on server and vice-versa. This solution removed large set of DTO (data transfer objects) and simplified code a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's no answer to your question other than "it depends". Or rather, of course there are ways of doing what you ask, but would you accept the tradeoffs?

Given that you tagged the question with dependency-injection, let's start with that. If you use a DI tool with GWT, it's likely GIN (Dagger 2 would work, but it's still under development). In that case, just use distinct modules for GIN client-side and Guice server-side that `bind()` the appropriate implementation.

For a few releases, `GWT.create()` can be made to work outside a GWT (client) environment (i.e. on the server side). You have to register a `ClassInstantiator` on the [`ServerGwtBridge`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/server/ServerGwtBridge.html) as an alternative to the rebind rules from `gwt;xml` files. So you could have a `<replace-with class="my.gwt.client.ClientFacadeImpl">` rule in your `gwt.xml`, and a `ClassInstantiator` returning a `ServerFacadeImpl` on the server side.

Finally, you can also use a static factory and replace it with a client-side specific version by way of `<super-source>`.

A last one, but I'm unsure whether it'd work: you could use an `if`/`else` using `GWT.isClient()`, and annotate your `ServerFacadeImpl` with `@GwtIncompatible` to tell the GWT compiler that you know it's not client-compatible.